# Unable to upload contacts or create marketing campaigns with Google Cloud Platform and Sendgrid

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, sendgrid

I subscribed to Sendgrid (Essentials 40K Plan) through Google App Engine.

We can't upload contacts neither using the API or Sendgrid website. Sendgrid support says that the reason is because it's a reseller account (because I subscribed using Google Cloud Platform)

Is it true? The cost of the plans through Google Cloud Platform are the same as Sendgrid website. Should I have to unsubscribe from GCP and create a different account directly in Sendgrid? Or is it a bug from GCP or Sendgrid?

I'm planning to subscribe to a higher plan because we have thousands of users, but if we can't upload contacts or create marketing campaigns it is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they said you can't use the GCP package for Marketing Campaigns, I guess you can't. But you can create a direct SendGrid account, and use [code-level integration](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/index.html) to connect.

Either way, you should ask GCP support about this limitation as well, and let them know you'd like that feature. If it's an intentional limitation, your "tally" to add it is important for their product team.

Comment: Yes. I asked GCP. It's a limitation from them, so I signed up to sendgrid with a different account. Google will add that this functionality with a different billing subscription

Answer (score 1):

If you use cloud launcher to integrate sendgrid, it's linked to your google cloud  billing account, not your user or IAM group.

You cannot log in directly as a user, and if your switch billing accounts (or it expires, is closed etc) you can no longer access it (including contacts or templates)

Your best bet is to sign up separately - although if doing so it is pretty comparable in cost to other providers.